# Can I return a different Django Response based on whether or not the view is invoked from swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I am using **Django-Rest-Framework** for my API.  And I am documenting that API w/ swagger using **drf_yasg**.  One of my views returns a Django `FileResponse`.

When I access the view directly at "http://localhost:8000/api/my_documents/1"  it successfully displays the (PDF) file.  But when I access it via swagger it successfully returns a 200 but gives the following message:

> Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text.

This is b/c of [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5500) in swagger itself.  As suggested in that ticket, the problem goes away if I change the "Content-Disposition" response header from "inline" to "attachment". However, I don't want to *always* download the file.

My question is: Can I determine whether the request was made by swagger in the view and conditionally change the headers?  Something like:

```
class MyDocumentView(GenericAPIVIew):

  def get(self, request, pk):
    my_document = MyDocument.objects.get(pk=pk)
    response = FileResponse(my_document.file)  # (file is a FileField)

    # WHAT DO I PUT HERE ?!?
    if request.is_from_swagger:
      response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = response.headers["Content-Disposition"].replace("inline", "attachment")

    return response
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking the `request.headers.get('referer')`. There should be your `swagger` url in there.

Comment: That's an excellent idea.  But I'm using `drf_yasg`.  My `request.accepted_renderer` is an instance of `rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer`.

Comment: Maybe try checking the `request.headers.get('referer')`? There should be your `swagger` url in there, let me know how that goes.

Comment: That works fine.  Thanks very much.  If you adjust your answer, I'll accept it.